# Retain Old configuration if new one is invalid

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("person")
@RefreshScope
@Validated
public class PersonConfiguration {

    @NotBlank
    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RestController
class MessageRestController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonConfiguration personConfig;

    @RequestMapping("/message")
    String getMessage() {
        return personConfig.getName();
    }
}
```

Configuration in git:

```
person:
    name: aaaa
```

I have a rest service and it has configuration which is read from git using spring cloud config. 
In the configuration when name is not empty and when someone hits the `/message` endpoint it's returning name correctly. If someone changes the name to an empty string and when `/message` endpoint is called it's throwing a binding exception since name should not be blank.

If someone updates git config to an invalid value how can i hold off to the previous version of that config so that `/message` endpoint would still be functional with previous valid config

Comment: Not a current feature

Answer (score 0):

You could create validation logic within your PersonConfiguration.class in setter methods. For example, removing `@Validated` and `@NotBlank` you could just write:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("person")
@RefreshScope
public class PersonConfiguration {

    public String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (Strings.isBlank(name)) {
           this.name = "default";
        } else {
           this.name = name;
        }
   }
}
```